# How to keep the UI-Searchbar visible when user slide upward in tableview

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uislider

In my app when the user slide down the UI-searchbar become disappear, which I want but when the user slide up I want UI-Search bar become visible at once.
[image] [image]

I want to have code that tell me when the user had slide upward in tableview cell and enable the uisearch-bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tableHeaderView` for this type of work.

In your `viewDidLoad` write below code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

**// Take one view and subview that view in the tableview.**

    UIView *viewsearch=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,-10, 320,83)];
    [self.Yourtablename addSubview:viewsearch];


**//Now take any controls which you want to show in your header. e.x label,button,searchbar**

UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[lbl1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,100,20)];
lbl1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
lbl1.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
lbl1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;    
[viewsearch addSubview:lbl1];
lbl1.text= @"BUY THE NEW APPLE TV FROM THE APPSTORE";

**//Here is the code.With the help of this code  when you scroll UP the headerview hide.**


 self.Yourtablename.tableHeaderView = viewsearch;
 self.Yourtablename.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(viewsearch.frame));

}
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: @bhumica->i want my uisearch bar visible when user slide up ward and how do i know if the user has slide upward or not

Comment: You are using table view and it will automatically identify.Just put this code.

Comment: @bhumica-->i got done with the ui-scrollbar delegate thanks for the help..can you tell me how to make ui-search bar visible not active as i am using --[self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:NO];
which will make it active i want it to be visible